# How to trace and check dependencies in bundled Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

Bundler will automatically install any dependencies for the specified gems, however it doesn't output which dependencies map to which gems in the standard output. That information is useful when one of the dependencies fails the installation.

Is there a way to set Bundler to be more verbose and inform about the dependencies while installing?

I am using Bundler 1.0.2

Comment: You can however use the "gem dependency" command to show the dependencies of a particular gem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To see a visual representation of the dependency tree run `bundle viz`:

```
apt-get install graphviz && gem install ruby-graphviz && bundle viz
```

It will generate a PNG file of the tree.

Comment: this won't work if there's still an outstanding unfulfilled gem dependency .. which gets back to the original problem.

Comment: For OSX, use homebrew: brew install graphviz && gem install ruby-graphviz && bundle viz

Comment: Would be nice to get a searchable list instead of an image here. Although the image is very cool.

Comment: Want to see a sample output? http://patshaughnessy.net/assets/2011/9/17/gem_graph.png

Comment: This was a horrible way of doing this. With a large amount of gems this becomes useless

Comment: not available anymore

Answer (score 7):

A less exciting, but equally effective way is to just do:

```
gem dep
```

which will generate a Gemfile.lock style output with dependency information.  You could pipe this output to `less`:

```
gem dep | less
```

Or, if you are searching for a failing dependency, you could grep it with some context.  For instance, to find out where my failing Thin dependency was coming from (fails with JRuby), I did:

```
gem dep | grep -C 15 thin
```

Comment: Or `gem dep -R thin`