# Bundler halts on json install, even though there's no json in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, json, rvm, bundle, bundler

Project bundle is stopping with error on json installation. But I'm not asking for json in Gemfile. Current Ruby in RVM is 1.9.2-p290, strict.

Have no idea to workaround this. Any helps, maybe?

```
 Installing json (1.7.7) 
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
 creating Makefile

 make
 xcrun cc -I. -     I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O3 -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common   -c generator.c
 xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
 cc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -pipe -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -o generator.bundle generator.o -L. -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib -L. -arch i386 -arch x86_64     -lruby  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: generator.o: No such file or directory
 i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: generator.o: No such file or directory
 lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:     /var/folders/ft/gswz6cs52wb9jh_v5h2yt5_h0000gn/T//ccvGNawc.out
 make: *** [generator.bundle] Error 1


 Gem files will remain installed in /Users/noAlvaro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@heroku_project/gems/json-1.7.7 for inspection.
 Results logged to /Users/noAlvaro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@heroku_project/gems/json-1.7.7/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

 An error occurred while installing json (1.7.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
 Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any help, anything, will be much appreciated. :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009767/rails-install-xcrun-error-failed-to-exec-real-xcrun/18244859#18244859 for options on getting the `json` gem to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't explicitly list `json` as dependency, other gems you are using may do this. As a result, Bundler will include it in the bundled list.

To check which library is using `json` you can inspect the Gemfile.lock file or use [bundle viz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868992/bundler-trace-and-check-dependencies-in-bundled-ruby-gems) to draw your dependency tree.

Comment: Thanks Simone. Among many `json` references in `Gemfile.lock`, the only `1.7.7` version is in path `GEM > specs: > json (1.7.7)`. The others are from lesser/no versions. How can I figure wich is the proper dependency parent?